# Why does this rsyslog configuration work (template)?

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

I have managed to come up with the following working config for *rsyslog*. It monitors a logfile with entries in *JSON* format, and shortens/normalizes them using a template. The shortening is needed, since I'm forwarding messages with *omfwd* over UDP (I can not use TCP), and thus each entry needs to fit in the datagram of a single package.

I am wondering why my template is being used, even though I do not reference it from an action in the ruleset. I used to do that (to produce a normalized log to pull in with *imfile*), but I have realized I do not have to do that.

I'm worrying what other log entries could potentially try to use my template. What prevents all the  other messages handles by *rsyslog* from using the template? Is the fact that *mmjsonparse* only parses messages with the *CEE* tag helping me here? I don't have any other services logging in *JSON* format on the machine.

I'm running *Ubuntu*, and the following config is pulled in from */etc/rsyslog.d/70-json-normalization.conf*. *rsyslog* is version *8.16.0*.

```
# Load "Text file input module"
# https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html
module(load="imfile" mode="inotify")
# Lod module to parse JSON
module(load="mmjsonparse")

# Template to normalize format of log messages from git-mirroring-service
# All log entries will have the same fillds after having passed through this
# Fields may have value ""
template(name="shorten-json" type="list" option.jsonf="on") {

  # Need to truncate these fields, since they can be very long, and we are
  # limited to 1400 bytes because we use UDP. Let's grab the first 400 chars.
  property(outname="error" name="$.json!error" format="jsonf" position.from="1" position.to="400")
  property(outname="stderr" name="$.json!stderr" format="jsonf" position.from="1" position.to="400")

  # All other fields (potentially) in the json are added with no change
  property(outname="level" name="$.json!level" format="jsonf")
  property(outname="configDir" name="$.json!configDir" format="jsonf")
  property(outname="msg" name="$.json!msg" format="jsonf")
  property(outname="name" name="$.json!name" format="jsonf")
  property(outname="msg" name="$.json!msg" format="jsonf")
  property(outname="ts" name="$.json!ts" format="jsonf")
  property(outname="json_file" name="$.json!json_file" format="jsonf")
  property(outname="repo" name="$.json!repo" format="jsonf")
  property(outname="id" name="$.json!id" format="jsonf")

  # These fields are formated as numbers
  property(outname="workers" name="$.json!workers" format="jsonf" datatype="number")
  property(outname="pid" name="$.json!pid" format="jsonf" datatype="number")
}

# Use template to write out normalized log
ruleset(name="git-mirror-log") {
  # Pass the log line as JSON. Put it in variable $.json
  action(type="mmjsonparse" container="$.json")
}

# Normalize the raw git-mirroring-service logfile.
input(
  type="imfile"
  reopenOnTruncate="on"
  # Prefix lines with "@cee:" so mmjsonparse will parse it
  addCeeTag="on"
  file="/var/log/git-mirroring-service/git-mirroring-service.log"
  tag="git-mirroring-service-service"
  ruleset="git-mirror-log"
)
```

Comment: _rsyslog_ version is _8.2001.0_ (It seem I cant edit the post).

Comment: I don't know, where you got the max of 1400 bytes for udp from (link MTU?). It looks to me like `mmjsonparse` handles the entire message (and doesn't shorten it). Are you sure that `shorten-json` is used?